# HTML character entity for equal character "="

Tags: html, character-encoding

What is the character entity for the equal character in HTML?  I have been looking and I cannot find the character entity reference for that one character.

EDIT:

I am building a JSLint style validator for HTML.  I am not happy with current validators as they only validate syntax requirements and not best practice considerations.  I am requiring that the equal character in attribute values be escaped to prevent confusion between a legal value that contains and equal character and two illegal attributes that are not separated by a space.

Comment: 'A validator for HTML including best practice considerations.' Cool. Recent discussions relating to validator.nu doing this raised some dispute over what best practice was. Will the rules set for best practice be user configurable?

Comment: The tool is being written in JavaScript and is highly configurable internally, so yes, but the official tool will use definitions I dictate.  If people are actually interested in using the completely tool I will be open to well argued changes.  It will be strict by default placing definitions upon which child elements are allowed to which elements and what attributes are allowed and even what type of data an attribute value may be.  I have already written all those definitions and the error reporting engine.  I am currently working out bugs and writing unique rules for certain elements.

Comment: `&#61;` BTW, I created an intuitively ordered HTML Character Code Picker (w optional click to clipboard) for the world https://hightechtele.com/tools/codes

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use [asciitable.com](http://asciitable.com/). `=` has ASCII value `61`, so the HTML entity is `&#61;`.

Comment: That's actually a numeric reference, not an entity. An entity is something that has a name, like `&quot;` or `&apos;`.

Comment: HTML Entities can use names or numbers : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 5):

You can use `&#61;`, but it's not really necessary to escape = in HTML.

Comment: I've found that I have to escape it when using == within a <pre><code></code></pre> element combo in the markdown parser for my blog engine.

Answer (score 5):

The character entity for the equal character, working with most browsers, is `&equals;`.
This will not work with Safari version 3.

Reference : https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/EqualsCharacterEntity

`&equals;` is not supported in HTML4 standards : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html
`&equals;` is supported in HTML5 standards : http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

For a better cross-browsers compatibility, you should use the `&#61;` entity.
If you want to be only-HTML5 compliant, I think the best is `&equals;`.

Answer (score 5):

There's also this `%3D` in percent-encoding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 0):

`&#61;`

But—why?

Answer (score 0):

```
&#61;
```

If http://www.december.com/html/spec/codes.html is to believed, that is.